# Need Fixes for HUD - MINECRAFT

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

Recently, I have installed the Replay Mod and the Optifine mod. After clicking around in the menus, I found that my hotbar and crosshair has vanished. Any fixes?

Comment: Try pressing F1.

Comment: F1 isn't the problem, I can still see the item held but not the hotbar and crosshair.

Comment: Does the same happen in Vanilla?

Answer (score -1):

The F1 key toggles any screen overlays including hotbar, pumpkinblur, crosshairs, etc. Though blocks will still show, as well as menus You may have accidentally pressed it. Try pressing F1 again, and it may bring back your hotbar and crosshairs.